# How to use either of proc_create or create_proc_entry depending on Linux kernel version

Tags: linux-kernel

Inside a Linux kernel module, using the macro `KERNEL_VERSION`, how I can use
either of the `create_proc_entry` or `proc_create` ?

Exactly in which kernel version, the interface got changed ?

I see that in kernel version 3.9, in the file `proc_fs.h` both the APIs are present under
different `#ifdef`'s. Basically I want to check kernel version and depending on that
call the correct API.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <linux/version.h>  /* For LINUX_VERSION_CODE */

#if ( LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(3,9,0) )
    /* 
     * Do This
     */
#else
    /* 
     * Do This
     */
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks Sundeep. In Kernel version 3.9.0, in proc_fs.h, I see that both create_proc_entry and proc_create are defined under #ifdef CONFIG_PROC_FS create_proc_entry #else proc_create #endif That's why the code snippet given by you won't work. What is CONFIG_PROC_FS ? Is it available to a kernel module ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is available - I just tried on Linux 3.2.0-80-generic (Ubuntu 12.04)

## if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < VERSION(3,11,0) && defined(CONFIG_PROC_FS)

and when this condition is met I use create_proc_entry() otherwise proc_create().